# Immutable vs Observable collections in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When using Flutter with realtime databases, such as Firebase Database, it is beneficial to know not just that a collection has been updated, but where exactly. Such as to show a pretty [list animation](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list), or trigger some additional events based on which item has updated. Dart already has an [amazing infrastructure](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) for delivering events.

A canonical example is to use a [FirebaseAnimatedList](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_animated_list/ui_firebase_animated_list-library.html), but it's glued to Firebase and doesn't support filtering and ordering (outside of very basic [Firebase model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)). I am looking for a more generic solution, which would allow to inject some logic between database (that notifies of item change/insert/delete), and aforementioned AnimatedList, which expects the same events.

Most recent tendency seems to be in favor of immutable collections, such as [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart), which makes a lot of sense in Dart, as object creation is [very cheap](https://hackernoon.com/why-flutter-uses-dart-dd635a054ebf?gi=8830355e9c3c). However, immutable collections do not have a way of telling which item has changed, they simply deliver a new collection. This approach also makes it difficult to attach some local information to an item, such as "selected" bit when user multi-selects items, or custom ordering. Because, well, items are immutable, and their reference (aka pointer, aka object ID) keeps changing.

One alternative solution is to implement a kind of observable list, such as what [package:observable](https://github.com/dart-lang/observable) offers, but it seems that its authors are not convinced of its popularity anymore. So what is the approach you take to create animated, filtered, sorted, selection-supporting lists in Flutter, backed by a realtime database?

Answer (score 0):

> However, immutable collections do not have a way of telling which item has changed, they simply deliver a new collection.

Some pseudo code: `(old collection) - (new collection) = (what changed)` - works the other way around too.

> This approach also makes it difficult to attach some local information to an item, such as "selected" bit when user multi-selects items, or custom ordering.

Extend said 'item' and add a property `selected` (or `order`, or any other info you want available), then just construct the new list with these properties properly set.

There are a lot of state-management-with-Flutter-related questions around these days, so to avoid repeating myself, I would rather link you to [an answer of mine from earlier today.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406897/flutter-keep-page-static-throughout-lifecycle-of-app/56407512#56407512)

***Edit:***

I just want to insert a practical example regarding `(old collection) - (new collection) = (what changed)`:

Basically this is how to see what changed when comparing 2 lists, containing closely related elements.

```dart
List currentState = [...];
List nextState = [...];

List addedItems = nextState.where((e) => !currentState.contains(e)).toList(),
List removedItems = currentState.where((e) => !nextState.contains(e)).toList();


doSomethingWith(addedItems);
doSomethingElseWith(removedItems);
```

Of course you should keep in mind that the Lists should be deeply comparable, i.e. for Dart's specific case you can use `built_value` or `equatable` packages.

I have also uploaded a [repository](https://github.com/komapeb/dart-tests), with a pure Dart project example. You're more than welcome to do whatever you want with the code.

Comment: That pseudo code is quite inefficient, given that "what changed" is what database gives in the first place. And finding previous item positions to properly animate it is even harder. Extending item is not an option for the same reason: once new data arrives, any additional state will be overwritten.

Comment: I've read the answer about state management, which is nice but doesn't tell anything new. Unfortunately, it does not help at all in answering my question.

Comment: Can't you keep a reference to the old state and when you receive data (new state) from the DB just compare it to that reference. Then just destroy the reference to the old data (if it's some kind of a listenable), or just let GC do its job.
I would also suggest using https://pub.dev/packages/equatable instead of built_value (although, their built-in serialization is quite nice) for comparing instances of the same class.

Comment: @J.Williams I've updated my answer with some more practical code.
I also took a look at AnimatedList and can confirm it's kind of a mess. It's mixing declarative with imperative logic (namely AnimatedListState's removeItem() and insertItem())... but in the end this same logic in my comment should work for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, this counts as a viable way to solve this, but pretty hard to pick up. It has quite a few drawbacks: any field change looses the whole state of an item because it's "removed"; we discard convenient and efficient database add/remove/change events; pagination will be inefficient because the whole list is recomputed (O(n^2) full comparisons); AnimatedList operates indexes, so it's going to be even more complicated. I am looking for something reusable, where I won't have to build a lot of boilerplate around.

Comment: I guess you already watched this, but the referenced example in your question is marked "out-of-date", so here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtfItHwFlZ8
I haven't looked at the source of `AnimatedList` but I think it's maintaining its own internal duplicate of the list, because of `removeItem()`...  because maybe it needs to keep a reference to the object being removed until the animation finishes?
One thing you could try is use the `old - new = changed` logic and build your own implementation of `AnimatedList` with maybe a `ListView` wrapped in a `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: All in all this is an interesting problem and I'll try to solve it when I have more time for playing around. Maybe even try to build a `BetterAnimatedList` package :P

Comment: AnimatedList doesn't have access to list data, so it can't hold a copy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is marked "out-of-date", and where?

Comment: Yeah, you're right about that, it doesn't have access to the Iterable.
About the out of date stuff: https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list there's a message at the bottom of this page saying "This page is deprecated and its content may be out of date."