# Flutter - Keep page static throughout lifecycle of app?

Tags: flutter

I have created an AppDrawer widget to wrap my primary drawer navigation and reference it in a single place, like so:

```dart
class AppDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Page1"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Page1.singleInstance));
              }
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Page2"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new Page2("Page 2")));
              }
            ),
          ]
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

I have also created a custom AppScaffold widget, which simply returns a consistent AppBar, my custom AppDrawer, and body:

```dart
class AppScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget body;
  final String pageTitle;

  AppScaffold({this.body, this.pageTitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(pageTitle), backgroundColor: jet),
      drawer: AppDrawer(), 
      body: body
    );
  }
}
```

I have created two pages: Page1, and Page2.  They are simple right now, and look something like this:

```dart
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pageText;

  Page1(this.pageText);

  static Page1 get singleInstance => Page1("Page1");

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
      pageTitle: this.pageText,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: SomeCustomWidget())
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pageText;

  Page2(this.pageText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
      pageTitle: this.pageText,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: SomeOtherCustomWidget())
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run my app, I can see the navbar and drawer correctly.  I can click on the links in the drawer to navigate between my pages.  However, each time I navigate to a page, all of the widgets on that page get reset to their initial state.  I want to ensure that the widgets do not get reset.  Another way to think of this is: I only want one instance of each page throughout the lifecycle of the app, instead of creating them new whenever a user navigates to them.

I tried creating a static instance of Page1 that the Drawer uses when the onTap event is fired, but this does not work. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?  Do I need to convert to a Stateful widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you're in for a treat... This will be kinda long (sorry) but please read all of it before making decisions and taking action - I promise I am saving you time.

There are many different solutions to this problem, but in general what you're asking about is state management (which is really software engineering, more info here - [Understanding state management, and why you never will](https://medium.com/fluttery/understanding-state-management-and-why-you-never-will-dd84b624d0e)).

I'll try my best to explain what is happening in your specific case...

**Problem:**

Think of `Navigator` as a `List` of application states, which you can manipulate via its various methods (i.e. `pop()`, `push()`, etc.), with this in mind it is clear what is happening - on a button press you're actually removing the current state (page) and right after that you're pushing a new instance of your state (page).

**Solution(s):**

As I said, there are many solutions to this problem, for example, you may be tempted to store the state (the changes you made to a particular "page") somewhere in a var and inject that var when navigating between "pages", when creating a new instance of that page, but you'll soon run into other problems. This is why I don't think anyone can provide a simple solution to this problem...

First, may I suggest you some useful reads on the matter:
[Flutter official docs on state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) - When you get to the "Options" section of this, the fun part begins and can quickly get overwhelming, but fear not :P

Be sure to read the medium article mentioned in the start of my answer too, I found it really helpful.

These reads will be more than enough to help you make a decision, plus there are a ton of articles on Medium and YouTube videos touching on the matter of state management with Flutter (even some from the authors of the framework) - just search for "State management with Flutter".

Now my own personal **opinion**:

If it's a really simple use case and you don't plan to grow (which is almost never the case, trust me), you can just use `StatefulWidget`s in combination with `setState()` and maybe `InheritedWidget` (for dependency injection down the tree, or like React guys call it "[lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)"). Or instead of the above, maybe have a look at [scoped_model](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model), which kinda abstracts all of this for you (tho, I haven't played with it).

What I use right now for a real world project is [`bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) and [`flutter_bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) (BLoC = Business Logic Component), I will not get into the details of it, but basically it takes the idea of `scoped_model` one step further, without over-complicating abstractions. `bloc` is responsible for abstracting away the "business logic" of your application and `flutter_bloc` to "inject" the state in your UI and react to state changes (official Flutter position on the matter is that [`UI = f(State)`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative)).
A BLoC has an input and an output, it takes in events as an input (can be user input, or other, any type of event really) and produces a state. In summary that's it about `bloc`.
A great way to get started is [BLoC's official documentation](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/gettingstarted). **I highly recommend it.** Just go through everything.

*(p.s. This may be my personal opinion, but in the end state management in Flutter is all based on some form of using `InheritedWidget` and `setState()` in response to user input or other external factors that should change the application state, so I think the BLoC pattern is really on point with abstracting those :P)*

Comment: `UI = f(State)` is a core of Flutter design, not a position. It's a great way of explaining how Flutter works. However, even being a big fan, I wouldn't recommend *starting* with BLoC. There are lots of pitfalls (text input state, back button, confirmation dialogs, validation, data save notifications) and a hanging state between things like checkbox click and its value propagation is a mess to follow. You did not mention [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), which might be an easier start for simple architectures, if you're not planning on reusing the code for AngularDart etc.

Comment: @J.Williams Good point, thanks for the clarifications. I did omit Provider on purpose, because it's already in the links I provided (no pun intended), but it's definitely something to look into. I would have put it between scoped_model and BLoC.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I managed to hook up the Bloc library and now my app is persisting data across page views :)